# Using a contradiction to show something is not compact

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Consider the set of $3$ by $3$ matrices in $\mathbb{R}$ that have nonzero determinant. I want to prove that this is not compact preferably with a contradiction.

Attempt:

Since its a determinant it is continuous, its image is the set of nonzero real numbers which is not compact. Therefore it is not compact.

Granted this is pretty vague but I think I get the idea. I would like a proof by contradiction though.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can make your argument into a proof by contradiction. Assume the contrary that the set is compact. Then as det is continuous, the image of det is compact. But it contradicts the fact that image of det is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

The map $\det:\Bbb R^{3\times 3}\to\Bbb R$ is continuous. The continuous image of a compact set is compact. Is $\Bbb R\smallsetminus \{0\}$ compact?

Answer (score 0):

Your argument works as long as you prove that the image set is indeed $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ as you claimed. It shouldn't be hard, you just have to show that for any $r\neq 0$ there exists a $3\times 3$ matrix with determinant $r$.

Another way of showing it by contradiction is to use a connectedness argument. Assume that it is compact, and note that it is also open as a preimage of the open set $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ under a continuous function by definition (the determinant). Then as a compact set it is also closed, which means that it is both closed and open. Since the set of $3\times 3$ matrices is connected as it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{9}$, which is connected, then this means that your set is either the whole space of $3\times 3$ matrices or the empty set. Both instances are impossible, so you get a contradiction.

Comment: I would be happy with the observation that this is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and thus not compact. It depends on what can be taken as obvious, I suppose. Your proof is certainly accurate.

Comment: @MPW: If you can take the continuity of determinant as obvious, then the set in question equals $\mathrm{det}^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ and is thus open. It should also be very elementary that $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.